# Is Exchange protected from/allow back dated emails?

Tags: security, exchange-2003, audit

Does Exchange Server adequately protect against backdating items in a mailbox folder? I want to determine from an auditing perspective what level of risk exists/what trust can be put into Exchange database records.

- Is there a (mis)feature that allows
  end point users to modify the
  sent/recieved date fields on their own messages?
- Is there a reasonable way short of hand editing the files for an
  Exchange Server admin to make such a
  change?

And most importantly: Is there any kind of "sequence number" that we could use to audit Exchange records for evidence of date manipulation (ex. msg100 = Dec 15, msg101 = *Dec 10*, msg102 = Dec 16)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this really answers your question, but looking at the MSDN reference for the MailItem, and it's time properties may give you an idea what you can trust.

MailItem

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946(office.11).aspx

MailItem.CreationTime

- Returns a Date indicating the creation time for the Outlook item
- Read-only.
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211817(office.11).aspx

MailItem.LastModificationTime

- Returns a Date specifying the date and time that the Microsoft 
  Outlook item was last modified.
- Read-only.
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171467(office.11).aspx

MailItem.ReceivedTime

- Returns or sets a Date indicating the date and time at which the mail message, meeting item, or post was received.
- Read/write for the MeetingItem object; read-only for the MailItem and PostItem objects.
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171873(office.11).aspx

> Is there any kind of "sequence number" that we could use to audit Exchange records for evidence of date manipulation.

I don't believe so.  If you really need to audit at this level you may just need to keep a seperate copy of each message/item. Or perhaps you need to come up with a good backup/restore method.  If you suspect something check out an older version of the persons mailbox from your archives.